# chart_studio.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: python, plotly

Here is my code can you please help me to execute my code. Currently it fails with:

> chart_studio.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
train=pd.read_csv('titanic_train.csv')
#sns.heatmap(train.isnull(),yticklabels=False,cbar=False,cmap='cividis')
import cufflinks as cf
import chart_studio.plotly as py
cf.go_offline()
train['Fare'].iplot(kind='hist',bins=30)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
print(plt.show())
```

Full traceback is:

> C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/admin/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/me.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/admin/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/me.py", line 711, in train['Fare'].iplot(kind='hist',bins=30) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py", line 1218, in _iplot dimensions=dimensions,display_image=kwargs.get('display_image',True)) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\cufflinks\plotlytools.py", line 1471, in iplot filename=filename) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 135, in iplot url = plot(figure_or_data, **plot_options) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 280, in plot auto_open=False, File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 1087, in upload file_info = _create_or_overwrite_grid(payload) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py", line 1550, in _create_or_overwrite_grid res = api_module.create(data) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\grids.py", line 18, in create return request("post", url, json=body) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 206, in call return attempt.get(self._wrap_exception) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 247, in get six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2]) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise raise value File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\retrying.py", line 200, in call attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py", line 180, in request validate_response(response) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py", line 82, in validate_response raise exceptions.PlotlyRequestError(message, status_code, content) chart_studio.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: Authentication credentials were not provided.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Can you add the full traceback of your error to the question? There is one obvious error in your code above, in that it should just be `plt.show()` not `print(plt.show())` but either way, I've just run the above code and can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Do you have an account/are you attempting to authenticate Chart Studio? https://plotly.com/python/getting-started-with-chart-studio/

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer work with Pycharm and it doesn't have any effect over the work and i also found the code for that simply use below code and that will be perfectly work over pycharm .
plot(train['Fare'].iplot(kind='hist',bins=30))
It plot the graph according to the requirement in a new browser.